# Errno 17 File exists: 'example.bat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

```
with open('example.bat', 'x') as f:
    for line in f:
     print(line, end='')
```

i am trying to get my code to open a .bat file but get [Errno 17] File exists: 'filename.bat'. Can anyone help me with a solution

Comment: Using `'x'` mode opens the file for writing, and it requires that the file does NOT already exist.  But it looks like you're actually trying to read the file, not write it.  (Why are you using `'x'` mode if you don't know what it does?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file with r+ because you want to read it and it will create the file if not exist (x opens for writing if not exist) or use rw+ for read/write:

```
 with open('example.bat', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
     print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the .bat just writes out its command in the terminal in vs code how do i get it to actually get it to run the .bat file.